# LIKE operator for DATE type variable in T-SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I want to run a condition like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date_time LIKE '2019-02-02';
```

I've tried converting it into T-SQL which is something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date_time LIKE [dynamicDateVariable];
```

which results to how many rows are in that date right?

Now I tried putting it in an *IF* statement, like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM funnel_logs 
    WHERE date_time LIKE converted_date) = '1' THEN
    //... run code
ELSE
    //... run this code
END IF;
```

My Goal is to only get one(1) row count to ***run code*** but the problem is even though I have a one(1) row count for that date it still proceed to the *ELSE* statement and runs the ***run this code***.

**Note:** I'm using xampp and phpmyadmin to run this, and I'm running this process on a trigger. I've tried using the `CONVERT(VARCHAR, [dynamicDateVariable], 126) LIKE [dynamicDateVariable]` but it still doesn't work. There was also a `DATEPART()` but some says that it's not really considerable and I think having a `[dynamicDateVariable]` would have too much work to be processed.

Am I missing something? I'm new to T-SQL, so if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: MySql, T-SQL, phpmyadmin ... what do you use? Microsoft SQL Server or MySql?

Comment: If you're using MySql, you are not using T-SQL. MySql's sql dialect is called MySql. The T-SQL dialect is used in Microsoft's SQL Server and Sybase only. I don't know about MySql, but in T-SQL `LIKE` only works with string data types (char/nchar/varchar/nvarchar).

Comment: Simply do not use `LIKE` on a date.  String operators should not be used on `date`/`datetime` values.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you cannot perform `LIKE` operator with `DateTime` this way and for that you'll have to think of a work around.

- Split your `converted_date` date in Years, months and days (date you
  want to perform `LIKE` with)
- Use `DatePart` function to get separate Year, Month and Day Then
  perform Comparison.

Following is the code I tested myself on SqlServer:

```
declare @var int 
set @var = (SELECT 
                  COUNT(*) FROM t  
            WHERE --ddate LIKE '2019-02-22%')
                 (DATEPART(yy, ddate) = 2019) AND
                  DATEPART(mm, ddate) = 02 AND
                  DATEPART(dd, ddate) = 22)
IF (@var = 1) 
begin
    select 1
end
ELSE
begin
    select 2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL, the `LIKE` operator only works with string data types.

From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Determines whether a specific character string matches a specified pattern.

And later on:

> **Arguments**
>   *match_expression*
>   Is any valid expression of *character* data type.

Best practice for searching records where a `datetime`/`datetime2` column has a specific date (without time) is using `>=` for the date requested, and `<=` for one day after:

```
DECLARE @SearchDate Date = '2019-02-22';

SELECT Columns
FROM Table
WHERE DateTimeColumn >= @SearchDate
AND DateTimeColumn <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @SearchDate)
```

You can search for different ranges the same way - for instance - if you want to search for a particular month, set the date to the first of that month and instead of adding a day, add a month:

```
DECLARE @SearchDate Date = '2019-02-01';

SELECT Columns
FROM Table
WHERE DateTimeColumn >= @SearchDate
AND DateTimeColumn <= DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @SearchDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL script is not working because you are comparing integer with string.
i.e. 1 = '1'
Change '1' to 1 as below then it should work:

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM funnel_logs 
    WHERE date_time LIKE converted_date) = 1 THEN
    //... run code
ELSE
    //... run this code
END IF;

Comment: In such cases SQL Server will attempt to implicitly convert the string to integer. In this case, it will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE on character datatypes but not datetime. Datetime works differently. Have you tried using variables and then using >= and < operator like below?

```
DECLARE @Date1 date=‘2019-02-02;
DECLARE @Date2 date=DATEADD(day,1, @date1); 

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE date_time >= @Date1 
  AND date_time < @Date2;
```